# What should be marked `final` to resolve this Scala code smell?

Tags: java, scala, sonarqube, findbugs

I have trouble understanding the "code smell" reported by Sonarqube in my scala class. The message is something like:
`com.foo.bar.MyObject$.MODULE$ isn't final and can't be protected from malicious code`

And the first line in my code `package...` is tagged as having the issue (see below). I don't understand if Sonarqube wants Object to be marked final (which doesn't make sense in Scala) or if it's something to do with the imports. Can anyone help me understand?

```
package com.foo.bar

import com.foo.baz

Object MyObject {
  val myVal = ...
  def method = ...
}
```

Comment: You can make the object `final` although I would look for a **Scala** specific plugin of SonarQube instead of using something that examines byte code.

Comment: Making the object `final` did not help. SonarQube still complains. I don't understand why the `package` line is highlighted, this makes no sense. It comes from FindBugs `MS_CANNOT_BE_FINAL`. I see other repos just ignore this error, I guess I will too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how objects are turned to bytecode. If you want to get rid of this message, consider doing this:

```
package com.foo.bar

import com.foo.baz

final object MyObject {
  val myVal = ...
  def method = ...
}
```

this will do effectively nothing from perspective of scala code bit your linter will shut up, you can check your bytecode which will now reflect that variable

```scala
com.foo.bar.MyObject$.MODULE$
```

Is now final. This is because object instance turned into static _.MODULE$ variable inside class MyObject.